# How to capture and save an image using custom camera in Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-camera

How do I capture an image in custom camera and then save that image in android?

Comment: Camera using surfaceview in layout XML , and there i have two buttons , one is close and other is capture

Comment: Please refer this: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html

Comment: why don't you go with `Image capture intent` if you require those 2 buttons functionality only?

Comment: actually i dont know that and im new, what iam looking for is,  when i capture an image , i want to show it in next activity

Comment: @Vishnu If my answer is helping you then please accept it.

Comment: See this if you are using android 10 or later
[api level 29 and above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64102245/13261376)

Answer (score 105):

please see below answer.

Custom_CameraActivity.java

```
public class Custom_CameraActivity extends Activity {
    private Camera mCamera;
    private CameraPreview mCameraPreview;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        mCamera = getCameraInstance();
        mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
        FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
        preview.addView(mCameraPreview);

        Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
        captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            }
        });
    }

    /**
     * Helper method to access the camera returns null if it cannot get the
     * camera or does not exist
     * 
     * @return
     */
    private Camera getCameraInstance() {
        Camera camera = null;
        try {
            camera = Camera.open();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // cannot get camera or does not exist
        }
        return camera;
    }

    PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
            if (pictureFile == null) {
                return;
            }
            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
                fos.write(data);
                fos.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    };

    private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
        File mediaStorageDir = new File(
                Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
                "MyCameraApp");
        if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
            if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
                return null;
            }
        }
        // Create a media file name
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
                .format(new Date());
        File mediaFile;
        mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
                + "IMG_" + timeStamp + ".jpg");

        return mediaFile;
    }
}
```

CameraPreview.java

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements
        SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

    // Constructor that obtains context and camera
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
        super(context);
        this.mCamera = camera;
        this.mSurfaceHolder = this.getHolder();
        this.mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        this.mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // left blank for now
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format,
            int width, int height) {
        // start preview with new settings
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            mCamera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // intentionally left blank for a test
        }
    }
}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_capture"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Capture" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Add Below Lines to your androidmanifest.xml file

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Nice solution. But the camera preview is always focused 90 degree vertical, camera is not at all focused straight. What have to change for achieving the straight camera focus.?

Comment: In you `manifest.xml`, make activity landscape `android:screenOrientation="landscape"`

Comment: @Karthick: in CameraPreview.java file before startPreview() add  mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);

Comment: It's always save picture in landscape even if I have activity to portrait. Can you please help me on that? I am testing it with galaxy S3 phone.

Comment: I used the code snippet above but my application keeps crashing after I push the capture button. Here is the logcat for my crash:  `java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
            at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
            at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1194)
            at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1139)
            at com.test.camera.customcamera.Custom_Scan_Activity$1.onClick(Custom_Scan_Activity.java:47)`

Comment: Hi @Dipak Keshariya, it works, thank you. Do you know how to make the new photos and folder visible within the default gallery app? Some kind of updating, I don't know.

Answer (score -3):

```
 showbookimage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                // create intent with ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE action
                Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                /**
 Here REQUEST_IMAGE is the unique integer value you can pass it any integer
 **/
                // start camera activity
                startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);
            }

            }

        );
```

then u can now give the image a file name as follows and then convert it into bitmap and later on to file

```
 private void createImageFile(Bitmap bitmap) throws IOException {
        // Create an image file name
        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 40, bytes);
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss").format(new Date());
        String imageFileName = "JPEG_" + timeStamp + "_";
        File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);
        File image = File.createTempFile(
                imageFileName,  /* prefix */
                ".jpg",         /* suffix */
                storageDir      /* directory */
        );
        FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(image);
        stream.write(bytes.toByteArray());
        stream.close();
        // Save a file: path for use with ACTION_VIEW intents
        mCurrentPhotoPath = "file:" + image.getAbsolutePath();
        fileUri = image.getAbsolutePath();
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(image).into(showbookimage);
    }
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode== Activity.RESULT_OK && intent != null){
            // get bundle
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            // get
            bitMap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
//            showbookimage.setImageBitmap(bitMap);
            try {
                createImageFile(bitMap);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }
```

use picasso for images to display rather fast