# Custom Camera returns null

Tags: android, camera

I am creating a custom camera in my application to take an image which returns null to my back activity...

this is my custom camera code.....

```
public class CustomCameraActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {

    public Camera mCamera;
    public SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    public SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    public boolean previewing = false;
    public LayoutInflater mLayoutInflater;
    public Button btn_Capture;
    public byte[] mPictureBytes;

    public Intent mIntent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.cameraview);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);

        getWindow().setFormat(PixelFormat.UNKNOWN);

        mIntent = getIntent();

        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.cameraView);
        mSurfaceHolder = mSurfaceView.getHolder();
        mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        mLayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(getBaseContext());
        View viewControl = mLayoutInflater
                .inflate(R.layout.controlbutton, null);
        LayoutParams layoutParamsControl = new LayoutParams(
                LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);
        this.addContentView(viewControl, layoutParamsControl);

        btn_Capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_capture);
        btn_Capture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                try {
                    mCamera.takePicture(myShutterCallBack, myPictureCallback_RAW, myPictureCallback_JPEG);
                    mIntent.putExtra("mPictureBytes", mPictureBytes);
                    Log.d("mPictureBytes", String.valueOf(mPictureBytes));
                    setResult(007, mIntent);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    ShutterCallback myShutterCallBack = new ShutterCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onShutter() {
        }
    };

    PictureCallback myPictureCallback_RAW = new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        }
    };

    PictureCallback myPictureCallback_JPEG = new PictureCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            try {
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                mPictureBytes = data;
            }
        }
    };
    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {
        try {
            if (previewing) {
                mCamera.stopPreview();
                previewing = false;
            }
            if (mCamera != null) {
                mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
                mCamera.startPreview();
                previewing = true;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera = Camera.open();
    }
    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;
        previewing = false;
    }
}
```

If i assign the data(byte[]) in finally block applicatio gose hang 
and  if i put it in try catch block it returns null......

**I want to send this Image or byte[] to my back activity.....**

Comment: Here you go

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913682/how-to-capture-and-save-an-image-using-custom-camera-in-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913682/how-to-capture-and-save-an-image-using-custom-camera-in-android

Comment: i had used this but the problem i want this byte array to my last activity but i didnt get it....
if i call it normally it gives me null.....