# Camera Tutorial for Android (using surfaceview)

Tags: android, surfaceview

Here is my example code:

```
package newslab.video.server;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class VideoServer extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    TextView testView;

    Camera camera;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

    private final String tag = "VideoServer";

    Button start, stop;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
        start.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                start_camera();
            }
        });

        stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
        stop.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                stop_camera();
            }
        });

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    }

    private void start_camera() {
        try{
            camera = Camera.open();
        }catch(RuntimeException e){
            Log.e(tag, "init_camera: " + e);
            return;
        }
        Camera.Parameters param;
        param = camera.getParameters();
        //modify parameter
        param.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
        param.setPreviewSize(176, 144);
        camera.setParameters(param);
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(tag, "init_camera: " + e);
            return;
        }
    }

    private void stop_camera() {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

However, it just shows the preview and stop the camera.
Is there any other tutorial to teach further processing such as how to save the image or process the image with bitmap?

Comment: not using native camera means what? which camera you are using?

Comment: have you got the solution of your basic query?

Comment: one more question for below comment^^

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Ok. So here is the solution:

I am not adding any try catch.
This is simply for the capturing the image and storing it into the sdcard.

```
public class VideoServer extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
    TextView testView;

    Camera camera;
    SurfaceView surfaceView;
    SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    PictureCallback rawCallback;
    ShutterCallback shutterCallback;
    PictureCallback jpegCallback;
    private final String tag = "VideoServer";

    Button start, stop, capture;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_start);
        start.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                start_camera();
            }
        });
        stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_stop);
        capture = (Button) findViewById(R.id.capture);
        stop.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
        {
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                stop_camera();
            }
        });
        capture.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                captureImage();
            }
        });

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
        rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - raw");
            }
        };

        /** Handles data for jpeg picture */
        shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
            public void onShutter() {
                Log.i("Log", "onShutter'd");
            }
        };
        jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
            public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
                FileOutputStream outStream = null;
                try {
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format(
                            "/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                    outStream.write(data);
                    outStream.close();
                    Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {
                }
                Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
            }
        };
    }

    private void captureImage() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        camera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
    }

    private void start_camera()
    {
        try{
            camera = Camera.open();
        }catch(RuntimeException e){
            Log.e(tag, "init_camera: " + e);
            return;
        }
        Camera.Parameters param;
        param = camera.getParameters();
        //modify parameter
        param.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
        param.setPreviewSize(176, 144);
        camera.setParameters(param);
        try {
            camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
            camera.startPreview();
            //camera.takePicture(shutter, raw, jpeg)
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(tag, "init_camera: " + e);
            return;
        }
    }

    private void stop_camera()
    {
        camera.stopPreview();
        camera.release();
    }

    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

}
```

Don't press **caputure** button before the **start**,because I didn't checked it. I just wanted to show you that how to capture and store image into the **sdcard**.

Comment: for more info.visit this site http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/39.html

Comment: Your solution is perfect. But one more question, how can I get the captured image as bitmap to make further effect?

Comment: for that you have to take the captured image from the sdcard using this. Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("/path/images/imageName.jpg"); And you can do further operation onto the bitmap

Comment: @NarendraPal when i tap on start button it`s show : java.lang.RuntimeException: Fail to connect to camera service on logcat

Comment: @mahdi please look into the complete example code which is mentioned by me in comments and let me know if that is not working.

Comment: @NarendraPal I'm unable to access that link, can you please help me out?

Comment: i would like to add this to a widget app, but the surface view isn't allowed, any ideas??

Answer (score 13):

Dont forget to take the permission for using camera in Android Manifest file,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" ></uses-permission>
```

Also you have to take permission for storing images on SD Card,

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Answer (score 3):

Camera permission in `manifiest` file:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

Permission for storing image from `sdcard` in `manifiest` file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I was having issues with camera, figuring out how to implement and work with and came across this resources: [Camera preview](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Hardware/Camerapreview.htm). At the bottom of the page you have examples of the most common scenarios as well as the one in your original question:    [Take and preview Photo](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Hardware/TakeandpreviewPhoto.htm)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android 10 or later don't forget to add this in your manifest file

```
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
android:grantUriPermissions="true"
```