# android : camera preview using surfaceview

Tags: android

```
package com.example.preview;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
import android.view.SurfaceView;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class MainActivity extends Activity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
Button start,stop;
Camera camera;
private final String tag = "VideoServer";
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     start = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
     start.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
     {
         public void onClick(View arg0)
         {
          start_camera();
         }
     });

     stop = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
     stop.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener()
     {
        public void onClick(View arg0)
        {
         stop_camera();
        }
     });
     surfaceView = (SurfaceView)findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
     surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
     surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
  // surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}


        private void start_camera() 
        {

            try
             {
               camera = Camera.open();
             }
             catch(RuntimeException e)
             {
               Log.e(tag, "init_camera: " + e);
               return;
             }
             Camera.Parameters param;
             param = camera.getParameters();
             //modify parameter
            //param.setPreviewFrameRate(20);
             param.setPreviewSize(176,144);
             camera.setParameters(param);
             try 
              {
                camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
                camera.startPreview();
              } 
             catch (Exception e)
             {
                Log.e(tag, "init_camera: " + e);
                return;
              }
            }

        private void stop_camera()
        {
         camera.stopPreview();
         camera.release();
        }
        public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}

This is the code just to preview on clicking start button.
But there is some error. On clicking the preview is stopped is popped out. Any suggestions from any one will be appreciable. I have added every permissions that is required. Still its not working

logcat error

```
11-28 11:01:49.621: E/AndroidRuntime(3558): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-28 11:01:49.621: E/AndroidRuntime(3558): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-28 11:01:49.621: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at    com.example.preview.MainActivity.start_camera(MainActivity.java:64)
11-28 11:01:49.621: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at com.example.preview.MainActivity.access$0(MainActivity.java:51)
11-28 11:01:49.621: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at com.example.preview.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:32)
11-28 11:01:49.621: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:3511)
11-28 11:01:49.621: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14109)
11-28 11:01:49.621: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
11-28 11:01:49.621: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-28 11:01:49.621: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
11-28 11:01:49.621: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
11-28 11:01:49.621: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-28 11:01:49.621: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
11-28 11:01:49.621: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
11-28 11:01:49.621: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
11-28 11:01:49.621: E/AndroidRuntime(3558):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: paste your logcat so that we can easily find out the errors

Comment: http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/12/28/how-to-create-a-custom-layout-for-your-camera-in-android/ -- have a look at this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you set the permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`?

// permission for camera

**Update :** Use the answer by `Narendra Pal` on this SO- [Camera Tutorial for Android (using surfaceview)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273976/camera-tutoial-for-android-using-surfaceview#12274334)

On devices without back-facing camera `Camera.open() returns null`. Try `Camera.open(0)` to get front camera. If you are using emulator, make sure you have enabled camera for your emulator device.

Comment: I have added all those

Comment: what is on `MainActivity.java:64`?

Comment: Verify the code with this so http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273976/camera-tutoial-for-android-using-surfaceview#12274334

Comment: even i dont know what is happening with the class Main Activity.i verified it ...its perfect

Comment: have you added this in your mainfest `<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
 <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />`

Answer (score 0):

from what I can guess here is that the `Camera` instance that you obtained by calling `CAmera.open()` is `null`. Are you getting any exception in your catch block here??

```
 try
 {
 camera = Camera.open();
 }
 catch(RuntimeException e)
 {
 Log.e(tag, "init_camera: " + e);
 return;
 }
```

Comment: On making it run, the screen comes with a error " preview is closed" This is all i can see

Comment: @user3040168 insert a debug point at `camera = Camera.open();` statement and run the app in debug mode. When you hit the breakpoint press F6 and then check in the debug pointer goes into the catch block or to the statement after the catch block.

Comment: i got it...it was the same line... i changed the API 8 to 9 and gave the id...WORKED!!!