# Taking photo in android without using intent

Tags: android, camera

I managed to make an activity that shows the camera preview. I have added a button on the screen to capture the photo. I wish to do it without using the intent( which calls another camera apps). I want it to be done within my apps. Any help or advice is greatly appreciated?

Comment: You should use the search: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273976/camera-tutoial-for-android-using-surfaceview

Answer (score 0):

Utilize google for these types of questions.

As a resource for useful informations I strongly suggest developer.android.com. This should your first reference if you encounter problems. 
For your question regarding taking pictures, the have an article already: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera