# Capturing Photo from SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-camera, surfaceview

I'm trying to capture an image from a SurfaceView custom camera. I have set up the initial code but I don't know how to call the 'take photo' method so that I can see the preview on the surface.

**Currently this code displays the preview in realtime. I need to take the picture and access the byte[] array**

Please help me complete the code:

```
    private SurfaceView mSurfaceView;
    private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
    private Camera mCamera;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);


        captureImage = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.captureImage);
        mSurfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);

        captureImage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                  //this button press should take the picture

            }
        });

        mSurfaceView.getHolder().addCallback(this);
        mSurfaceView.getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

        mCamera = Camera.open();
    }

@Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mCamera.stopPreview();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mCamera.release();
    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        try {
            mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(mSurfaceView.getHolder());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
        Camera.Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
        List<Camera.Size> sizes = params.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
        Camera.Size selected = sizes.get(0);
        params.setPreviewSize(selected.width,selected.height);
        mCamera.setParameters(params);

        mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        mCamera.startPreview();

    }


    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
        mCamera = null;

    }
```

I need to get the bytes [] data so that I can convert the image to a base64 string. How do I call the necessary methods to take the picture using the code above?

Comment: implement  `Camera.PictureCallback`

Comment: @MD could you should me a code sample please? I tried doing that but I'm a bit confused. How do I get the byte[] from it?

Comment: Wait i will post sample code

Comment: [http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/surfaceview/android-surfaceview-example/](http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/surfaceview/android-surfaceview-example/)

Comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273976/camera-tutorial-for-android-using-surfaceview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273976/camera-tutorial-for-android-using-surfaceview)

Comment: You need to add callback.

Comment: You need to call takePicture method.

Answer (score 4):

Check "jpegCallback" in my example:

```
public class CameraActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback {
Camera camera;
SurfaceView surfaceView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;

PictureCallback jpegCallback;

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_camera);

    surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();

    // Install a SurfaceHolder.Callback so we get notified when the
    // underlying surface is created and destroyed.
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

    // deprecated setting, but required on Android versions prior to 3.0
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                outStream = new FileOutputStream(String.format("/sdcard/%d.jpg", System.currentTimeMillis()));
                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
                Log.d("Log", "onPictureTaken - wrote bytes: " + data.length);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
            }
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Picture Saved", 2000).show();
            refreshCamera();
        }
    };
}

public void captureImage(View v) throws IOException {
    //take the picture
    camera.takePicture(null, null, jpegCallback);
}


@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    try {
        // open the camera
        camera = Camera.open();
    } catch (RuntimeException e) {
        // check for exceptions
        System.err.println(e);
        return;
    }
    Camera.Parameters param;
    param = camera.getParameters();

    // modify parameter
    List<Camera.Size> sizes = param.getSupportedPreviewSizes();
    Camera.Size selected = sizes.get(0);
    param.setPreviewSize(selected.width,selected.height);
    camera.setParameters(param);
    try {
        // The Surface has been created, now tell the camera where to draw
        // the preview.
        camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // check for exceptions
        System.err.println(e);
        return;
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    // Now that the size is known, set up the camera parameters and begin
    // the preview.
    refreshCamera();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    // stop preview and release camera
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
    camera = null;
}

public void refreshCamera() {
    if (surfaceHolder.getSurface() == null) {
        // preview surface does not exist
        return;
    }
    // stop preview before making changes
    try {
        camera.stopPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // ignore: tried to stop a non-existent preview
    }

    // set preview size and make any resize, rotate or
    // reformatting changes here
    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        camera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}
```

}