# Can you display the real-time output of the device's camera?

Tags: java, android, camera

I am wondering if it is possible to show the output of the camera running on your device immediately on the screen. Just like the native camera app does.

I have to show the picture, that comes into the camera lens, and additionally add some graphics overlays. That's why I guess, starting an Intent to open the camera activity is not suitable.

I've found some SO Threads, Tutorials and documentation about using the Android Camera API, but they are all able to just take a picture and display it afterwards.

Is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this link [Camera Tutorial for Android (using surfaceview)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273976/camera-tutorial-for-android-using-surfaceview)!

Use the SurfaceView to preview the camera output, then, you can add your graphics overlays as you wish.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you. I tried this one, but the preview remained black.  [This link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Hardware/Camerapreview.htm) let me know, that I had to call `camera.startPreview` from with in the `surfaceChanged()` method ...

Comment: Did you try it on the surfaceChanged() method? It did work for you?

Comment: Yes. It worked. `startPreview()` has to be called and parameters have to be set in `surfaceChanged()`, as far as I know now.