# Is there a way to open camera and view it on screen and make is so it is not able to take pictures or record videos.

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2

I am creating a android app which has the following requirement and can you tell how to implement it.

1) Open Camera in a fragment,
2) Should not be able to record videos or take pictures.

I am new to android, so it will very helpful if you guys help me out here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want the camera view and not its actions(buttons). You can use SurfaceView to create your own camera. This will just open camera. You can find surface view tutorial [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12273976/camera-tutorial-for-android-using-surfaceview).You can just exclude the part where they are adding the start, stop and capture buttons.

don't forget the permission 
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" ></uses-permission>` in your `manifest` .

Answer (score 0):

The best practice to achieve your requirement is through surface view.

 **SurfaceView** in android provides a way to show camera on the device to user.
It provides various classes, so that you can customize the camera and add your functionalities to it as per your need.

Mentioned below are few links, that will guide you through surface view:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html
https://www.airpair.com/android/android-camera-surface-view-fragment

Hope this helps.