# Get path and imagename of recently captured image through camera

Tags: android, image, ftp, camera

I have to upload captured image to ftp server.I am capturing image through camera and i want to get image name and path of that image.I am using following code to get imagepath:

```
int ACTION_TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
String selectedImagePath;
Uri mCapturedImageURI;

Button loadButton;
ImageView img;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_new_ftpsdemo);
     img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "yahoo.jpg");
    mCapturedImageURI  = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
    Intent intentPicture = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intentPicture.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);
    startActivityForResult(intentPicture,ACTION_TAKE_PICTURE);

}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if(requestCode == ACTION_TAKE_PICTURE){
        selectedImagePath = getRealPathFromURI(mCapturedImageURI);
        Log.v("selectedImagePath", selectedImagePath);
        img.setImageBitmap( BitmapFactory.decodeFile(selectedImagePath));
    }
}


public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri)
    {
        try
        {
            String[] proj = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
            int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            return cursor.getString(column_index);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return contentUri.getPath();
        }
    }
```

But i am getting imagepath like this:

```
/mnt/sdcard/DCIM/Camera/1352443194885.jpg
```

As i am saving name  "yahoo.jpg".
I know this may be very simple question but i am unable to get imagename and path same.
So i am unable to upload image to ftp server.

Comment: If you are comfortable storing the image from the camera in your own folder, I may have a solution for you.

Comment: Any solution is always welcome to me.. Just i want full path and image name of captured image.

Comment: How you solved this problem ?

Comment: @kamil I have posted the solution below.It works for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a resolved the issue with the following code.It works for me.

I have referred this link:[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913682/how-to-capture-and-save-an-image-using-custom-camera-in-android)

Just have to make filepath and imageName global variable

MyCameraActivity.java

```
public class MyCameraActivity extends Activity {
private Camera mCamera;
private CameraPreview mCameraPreview;
public static String imageFilePath;
public static String imageName;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    mCamera = getCameraInstance();
    mCameraPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mCameraPreview);

    Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Helper method to access the camera returns null if it cannot get the
 * camera or does not exist
 * 
 * @return
 */
private Camera getCameraInstance() {
    Camera camera = null;
    try {
        camera = Camera.open();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // cannot get camera or does not exist
    }
    return camera;
}

PictureCallback mPicture = new PictureCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
        File pictureFile = getOutputMediaFile();
        if (pictureFile == null) {
            return;
        }
        try {
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(pictureFile);
            fos.write(data);
            fos.close();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
};

private static File getOutputMediaFile() {
    File filePath = new File(
            Environment
                    .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES),
            "MyCameraApp");

    if (!mediaStorageDir.exists()) {
        if (!mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
            Log.d("MyCameraApp", "failed to create directory");
            return null;
        }
    }
    // Create a media file name
    String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss")
            .format(new Date());
imageName = timeStamp +".jpg"; // name of captured image
    File mediaFile;
    mediaFile = new File(mediaStorageDir.getPath() + File.separator
            + imageName);
    imageFilePath = mediaFile.toString(); // you can get path of image saved
    return mediaFile;
}
```

}

CameraPreview.java:

```
public class CameraPreview extends SurfaceView implements
    SurfaceHolder.Callback {
private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder;
private Camera mCamera;

// Constructor that obtains context and camera
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public CameraPreview(Context context, Camera camera) {
    super(context);
    this.mCamera = camera;
    this.mSurfaceHolder = this.getHolder();
    this.mSurfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
    this.mSurfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
}

@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // left blank for now
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder) {
    mCamera.stopPreview();
    mCamera.release();
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder, int format,
        int width, int height) {
    // start preview with new settings
    try {
        mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder);
        mCamera.startPreview();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // intentionally left blank for a test
    }
}
```

}

main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/camera_preview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button_capture"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="Capture" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Following permissions are required in androidmanifiest.xml:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Now i can get imageName and imagepath of recently captured image and easily upload this image to ftp server.

Happy coding.

Comment: I use this code but camera preview is shown on camerapreview wrong. Do you have the solution for that ?

Comment: I am getting a null pointer exception at preview.addView(mCameraPreview); Please help ?

Answer (score 1):

check this...put this in your onActivityResult

```
           Uri selectedImage = intent.getData();

           String[] filePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA};
           Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage, filePathColumn, null, null, null);
           cursor.moveToFirst();
           int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
           String filePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
           Log.v("log","filePath is : "+filePath);
```

Answer (score 0):

While creating a path you are just saving the "title". You are not giving the actual path and the filename that the camera should use to store. Because of this Camera is storing the file at its default location with the "Title" you have provided.

You are doing all fine in your code but just do the following to have the same filename:

Intead of :

```
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, "yahoo.jpg");
mCapturedImageURI  =  getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);
```

Use this:

```
    StringBuilder path = new StringBuilder();
    path.append(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory());
    path.append(// any location say "/Pictures/" //); // Do check if the folder is present. Else create one.
    path.append("yahoo");
        path.append(".jpg");
    File file = new File(path.toString());
    mCapturedImageURI = Uri.fromFile(file);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to start the Intent for the Camera:

Oh. The `Uri targetURI` is a global declaration.

```
Intent getCameraImage = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");

File cameraFolder;

if (android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
    cameraFolder = new File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"your_app_name/camera");
else
    cameraFolder= StatusUpdate.this.getCacheDir();
if(!cameraFolder.exists())
    cameraFolder.mkdirs();

File photo = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "your_app_name/camera/camera_snap.jpg");
getCameraImage.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(photo));
targetURI = Uri.fromFile(photo);

startActivityForResult(getCameraImage, 1);
```

And in the `onActivityResult()`:

```
getContentResolver().notifyChange(targetURI, null);

ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

try {       
    // SET THE IMAGE FROM THE CAMERA TO THE IMAGEVIEW
    bmpImageCamera = android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(cr, targetURI);

    // SET THE IMAGE FROM THE GALLERY TO THE IMAGEVIEW
    imgvwSelectedImage.setImageBitmap(bmpImageCamera);

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This piece of code creates a *folder* with a name of your choice. You can change the folder name here: new `File(android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"your_app_name/camera");`

Also, this overwrites the `camera_snap.jpg` everytime you call the Intent to get a Camera image.

This code does not account for Out Of Memory exceptions, but is merely a demonstration of how to get Camera images back to your app.

EDIT: Almost forgot. If you haven't already done so, you will need to add this permission to your `Manifest.xml`: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`