# Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: android, android-camera

I am using this tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html

To **capture an image and save it on SD Card**, but whenever i run this program, getting : **Unfortunately App has Stopped**

**Error says:**

*Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException*

**Line Number 39 is:**

camera.takePicture(null, null,
        new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));

**Logcat output:**

```
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3599)
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3594)
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  ... 11 more
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.example.cameraapp.MakePhotoActivity.onClick(MakePhotoActivity.java:39)
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  ... 14 more
```

**MakePhotoActivity.java:**

```
  public class MakePhotoActivity extends Activity {
  final static String DEBUG_TAG = "MakePhotoActivity";
  private Camera camera;
  private int cameraId = 0;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    // do we have a camera?
    if (!getPackageManager()
        .hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA)) {
      Toast.makeText(this, "No camera on this device", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
          .show();
    } else {
      cameraId = findFrontFacingCamera();
      if (cameraId < 0) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "No front facing camera found.",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      } else {
        camera = Camera.open(cameraId);
      }
    }
  }

  public void onClick(View view) {
    camera.takePicture(null, null,
        new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));
  }

  private int findFrontFacingCamera() {
    int cameraId = -1;
    // Search for the front facing camera
    int numberOfCameras = Camera.getNumberOfCameras();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfCameras; i++) {
      CameraInfo info = new CameraInfo();
      Camera.getCameraInfo(i, info);
      if (info.facing == CameraInfo.CAMERA_FACING_FRONT) {
        Log.d(DEBUG_TAG, "Camera found");
        cameraId = i;
        break;
      }
    }
    return cameraId;
  }

  @Override
  protected void onPause() {
    if (camera != null) {
      camera.release();
      camera = null;
    }
    super.onPause();
  }
```

Comment: post your MakePhotoActivity

Comment: could not execute method of activity means some stuff yet not initilized.

Comment: @RajithaSiriwardena i have pasted

Comment: check whether your camera variable is null

Comment: @RajithaSiriwardena using this code: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidCamera/article.html

Comment: @ChulbulPandey check your line no 39 it gives you `NullPointorException`

Comment: @SilentKiller oh sorry forgot to tell you getting NPE here:  camera.takePicture(null, null,
        new PhotoHandler(getApplicationContext()));

Comment: @Chulbul Pandey check your line 39 you haved passed null value..

Comment: @SilentKiller buddy try this code at your end, i believe you will find solution

Comment: @ChulbulPandey you want to use frontcamera..??

Comment: simple camera is ok @SilentKiller

Comment: you wanna open default camera application or custom camera preview.?

Comment: default cam @SilentKiller

Comment: sorry buddy custom @SilentKiller, i have upvoted

Comment: @ChulbulPandey check Updated answer for custom camera links.. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To Open Android default Camera you write a simple 2 lines of code which are:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("android.media.action.IMAGE_CAPTURE");
startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
```

and to get the path of the clicked image you need to Override `onActivityResult()`. The following code helps you get the path of the clicked image:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
  if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && requestCode == 0) {
    String result = data.toURI();
    // ...
  }
}
```

Finally, in your manifest file, add a "Uses-Permission" for the camera.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
```

***: Updated Answer :***

**For Custom Camra**

Follow this links for Custom Camera:

1. [Custom Camera Application](http://capycoding.blogspot.in/2012/06/custom-camera-application.html)
2. [Custom camera for Android created for testing, playing and learning](https://github.com/dawidgatti/dgCam)
3. [How to capture and save an image using custom camera in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10913774/1160282)
4. [How to create a custom layout for your camera in Android?](http://www.coderzheaven.com/2011/12/28/how-to-create-a-custom-layout-for-your-camera-in-android/)

Comment: 2)Custom camera for Android created for testing, playing and learning   This example helps me to solve this issue. I refer CameraPreview class surfaceChanged method

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is here :

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  at com.example.cameraapp.MakePhotoActivity.onClick(MakePhotoActivity.java:39)
05-29 16:19:38.351: E/AndroidRuntime(767):  ... 14 more
```

Check what is wrong @ MakePhotoActivity.java, line 39.

Comment: Wish I could comment on other people questions. I don't have enough rep.

Answer (score 0):

Seems that your `camera` object is null

Answer (score -3):

You should need the camera on your AVD So edit your AVD and add camera on back as well as on front.....