# Is there a way to take a picture on android when flashlight is on(torch mode)

Tags: android, camera, tasker

I am using tasker to take pictures automatically, I am using front camera because my back camera is broken. The thing is, I need to take pictures at night too, but front camera don't have flashlight. So I downloaded a plugin to set flashlight on for 5 seconds before taking pictures, but when the task advanced to taking camera it reported an error (failed to start camera proxy) and stopped. I tried my another phone it's the same problem.

So I'm wondering is this a limitation on android (and all camera devices) or are there kernel settings we can temple with to make this work? I'm not familiar with android programming but from my understanding, the camera can't start because it would check if the flashlight is ready but it's occupied by torch application. So if I disable the flashlight check, it might work. I found a similar question [Strange android camera behaviour when torch is on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401494/strange-android-camera-behaviour-when-torch-is-on) , the author had the same problem in his app development and didn't seem to get a proper answer. Or is there a camera app which works when torch is on and can be called via tasker?

Comment: You are messing torch with flashlight. Flashlight is on the back side of the phone, while torch is on the front side Please, make a more specific question. If you want to use your torch when taking front camera pictures, you dont need the flashlight. You just turn on the torch.

Comment: [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FLASH_MODE_TORCH) Torch mean constant emission of light, I don't think there is any problem with my expression.