# Auto capture image from camera?

Tags: android, camera

I have qrReader app so  in ActivityResult i wrote to intent into the camera if I have response what I want that is it possible to take the picture automatically after the intent into the camera and after autofocus it ??(what should I have to add for autocapture)

```
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            IntentIntegrator intentIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
            intentIntegrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
            intentIntegrator.setPrompt("Scan");
            intentIntegrator.setCameraId(0);
            intentIntegrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            intentIntegrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            intentIntegrator.initiateScan();

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    final IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if(result!= null){
                if(result.getContents()==null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"you canceled the scanning",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    textView.setText(result.getContents());
                    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);



                }



    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

Comment: Post your code so we can suggest changes

Comment: added please check it in else what should add to capture picture automatically

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code:

Write a method

```
public void capturePhoto() throws Exception { 
        mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback);
        Thread.sleep(WAIT_GENERIC);
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();
    }
```

And call it in your onResult else as

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            IntentIntegrator intentIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
            intentIntegrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.QR_CODE_TYPES);
            intentIntegrator.setPrompt("Scan");
            intentIntegrator.setCameraId(0);
            intentIntegrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
            intentIntegrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
            intentIntegrator.initiateScan();

        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(final int requestCode, final int resultCode, final Intent data) {
    final IntentResult result = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode,resultCode,data);
    if(result!= null){
                if(result.getContents()==null){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"you canceled the scanning",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                    capturePhoto();
                    textView.setText(result.getContents());
                    startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);



                }



    }
```

To answer your question in your camera previewclass add:

```
ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {
            //           Log.d(TAG, "onShutter'd");
        }
    };

    PictureCallback rawCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            //           Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - raw");
        }
    };

    PictureCallback jpegCallback = new PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            new SaveImageTask().execute(data);
            resetCam();
            Log.d(TAG, "onPictureTaken - jpeg");
        }
};
```

Comment: what is the camera ... ?

Comment: Assuming you have initialized the camera earlier I have given you this code.

Comment: no this is my code i just added intent into camera even i dont have photohandler class

Comment: and what is shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback

Comment: See the edit to know about shutterCallback, rawCallback, jpegCallback

Comment: now SaveImageTask and             resetCam();
 is missing

Comment: Again there I am assuming you have written the custom camera class.

Comment: Can you please post your camera class

Comment: no no i don't have it i said it this is my full code

Comment: Create one using the following link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10913682/how-to-capture-and-save-an-image-using-custom-camera-in-android

Comment: i added those like u said then what ? still same errors missing method of save

Comment: have you written a custom camera class?as the above link?

Comment: yes but in those classes there isn't method call SaveImageTask()